# On linux/mono, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9") throws not supported exception

Tags: c#, linux, encoding, mono

This is a form based c# project. It works very fine in windows.
Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way would be not to use such a limited encoding for your data, and instead of UTF-8.

Comment: Program getting html from unfamiliar website. This is not my data:( I have to do this somehow

Comment: @eerrzz: is the page encoded as `ISO-8859-9`? Are you sure? Could you provide a link?

Comment: @eerrzz: Was that meant for @Matt Ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` also throw a `NotSupportedException`?

*Do you really need `ISO-8859-9`?* [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9):

> It is identical to ISO/IEC 8859-1 except for these[*] six replacements of characters mostly used to write the Icelandic language.

Even better would be, as [@Matti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227267/matti-virkkunen) commented, to use the *de facto* standard: UTF-8.

**Edit:** are you using MonoTouch? If so, you're probably experiencing [this issue](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Internationalization).

---

*The six replacements:

> **8859-1**: `Ð Ý   Þ   ð   ý   þ`
>   **8859-9**: `Ğ İ   Ş   ğ   ı   ş`

Comment: @eerrzz: You're welcome. Which solution worked? Using `ISO-8859-1`? The MonoTouch internationalization fix?

Comment: Im used "ISO-8859-1" encoding and replaced characters. Im not using monotouch.

Comment: @eerrzz: sounds a little bit hacked, but that's sure better than not working at all!